# Why sometimes there is outdated drivers on the hardware servers?

Tags: drivers

Many times I've seen third party software (eg Driver Genius) offering me to download versions of the drivers there are not yet published on the official websites of those companies.

- As at 07.09.2014

You can see a [good example in Realtek](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=13&PFid=5&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false), The driver they offer me to download is **7.088** while the [Driver Genius offers me](http://www.driverswizard.com/html/194090.html) is **7.089.0716.2014**.

I don't even mean to demand that they should give me an option to download
those drivers, But at the very least, They should let me know that they released a newer version and I can decide whether to download it or not...

Is there a logical explanation for this occasion?
Shouldn't I trust the drivers that third party companies/software offered me compared to what I can get from the official sites??

Comment: That Realtek site says "Best viewed at 800x600 with IE 6.0 or Netscape 7.02 or Mozilla Firefox 1.0.6 or higher."... That said, I don't think anyone can know the reasoning.

Comment: @Arjan It's not really relevant to my issue, They probably write that to cover the most of the users that have those condition (or better than that obviously), And didn't bother to change those condition to be more like 'nowadays'.

Comment: The fact that they didn't bother to change that line *might* make people think they don't bother to update their site for every new release of the drivers either, Hashirama. But that's all just guessing, which is [off-topic, I feel](http://superuser.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: @Arjan Please keep in mind that Realtek is only one example from the many companies that isn't updated. Maybe it wasn't bold enough for this demonstration because of the small distance of the date, But I can assure you there are much more "extreme" cases than this.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the most update driver doesn't mean its the best driver for you, there's issue with some hardware configuration beta drivers or bugs and etc.

If the legacy vendor if giving you those instead the most update ones, trust them.

Comment: Like I said earlier "at the very least, They should let me know that they released a newer version and I can decide whether to download it or not..."
BTW sometimes it's a years different apart from each of them, So I doubt that is the only case (probably not).

Comment: As far i can see, must be a patch for some specific hardware configuration, and the general purpose patch its the realtek one.

Comment: You are ignoring the main problem, It doesn't concern me what type of upgrade those the specific example that I gave here (at this moment at least). I just want to know why can't I access it directly from the main site + and why that it's happening regularly in many other sites.